# pick a number in array and avoid to pick the same number?

Tags: java, arrays

I want to make a function that pick a randomly number in array and avoid to pick the same number in next time.
Here is my code (it work in sometime and mostly inf-loop)
please help me, Thank you.

```
private static int pick(int[] x) {
    int upperbound = x[x.length-1];
    int lowerbound = x[0];
    int count=0;
    int ranvalue;
    int ranindex;
    Random rand = new Random();

    do{
        ranindex = rand.nextInt(upperbound-lowerbound) + lowerbound;
        count++;
    }while(x[ranindex]==-1||count!=x.length-1);

    ranvalue=x[ranindex];
    x[ranindex]=-1;

    return ranvalue;
}
```

Comment: it looks to me like your code only really tries to select one number, and it just keeps repeating so long as it's an invalid number.

Comment: If you merely want to avoid picking the same number twice in a row, you can keep track of your previous number.  IF you want to avoid picking duplicates at all, you might consider simply removing your value from your array(or linked list)

Answer (score 5):

If your array has size n, then you can get at most n different indexes. I advise the following :

- Create an array with numbers from `0` to `n-1`.
- Shuffle it.
- At each step, take the next element from this array and use it as an offset for your source array.

You should also wrap this logic into a class like this :

```
public class Picker {

  private int[] source;

  private List<Integer> offsets;

  private int currentIndex = 0;

  public Picker(int[] source) {
    this.source = source;

    Integer[] indexes = new Integer[source.length];
    for(int i=0;i<source.length;i++) {
      indexes[i] = i;
    }

    this.offsets = Arrays.asList(indexes);
    Collections.shuffle(this.offsets);
  }

  public Integer next() {
    return source[offsets.get(currentIndex++)];
  }

}
```

**Example :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  int[] source = {8,3,5,9};
  Picker picker = new Picker(source);

  for(int i = 0; i<4;i++) {
    System.out.println(picker.next());
  }
}
```

**Output :**

```
5
3
8
9
```

**EDIT** : Or even simpler :

```
Integer[] source = {8,3,5,9};

//Copy the source and shuffle it
List<Integer> dest = Arrays.asList(source);
Collections.shuffle(dest);

//Then display
for (int i = 0;i<source.length;i++) {
  System.out.println(dest.get(i));
}
```